# Tkinter windows in loop, get a TypeError

Tags: loops, tkinter, typeerror

I need to have a window with a button. I want this button to be linked to a command to close the window and after that to open the window again to be able to press the button again. 
This is it. And unfortunately it does not work. I do not get why. I get a 'TypeError: 'Tk' object is not callable' when I run it. 
Does anyone has an idea? 
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def window_1():
    global window_1
    window_1 = Tk()
    button_1 = Button(window_1, text='OK', command=command_1)
    button_1.pack()
    window_1.mainloop()

def command_1():
    window_1.destroy()
    window_1()

window_1()
```

Comment: You have both a function and a global variable by the same name. Rename one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is only happening because you are using a variable(`window_1`) that has a name exactly the same as a function.

**The solution** is simple. All you need to do is to change the name of the variable or the function to something else.

Like This:

```
from tkinter import *


def window_f():
    global window_1
    window_1 = Tk()
    button_1 = Button(window_1, text='OK', command=command_1)
    button_1.pack()
    window_1.mainloop()


def command_1():
    window_1.destroy()
    window_f()


window_f()
```